# Excel VBA @SQL String filter

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-filter

I have been struggling on making this statement a NOT statement:

```
strfilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " like '%undeliverable%'"
```

this strfilter is being used in a items.restrict(strfilter), so obviously it's checking for all emails that contains the word undeliverable.

What I need to do is convert this statement so that it will EXCLUDE all emails with the subject containing the Words "undeliverable".

I've tried this but it returned a parse error:

```
"strFilter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) & " NOT '%undeliverable%'"
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Would it be: `NOT Like '%undeliverable%'"`?

Comment: @RyanWildry That will still throw Error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***The Correct syntax is***

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & " Not " & _
         "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & "" & _
         " Like '%undeliverable%'"
```

***Or I prefer this then Like***

```
strFilter = "@SQL=" & " Not " & _
            "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & "" & _
            " ci_phrasematch 'undeliverable'"
```

Comment: hi 0m3r i will try this on monday in my office. thanks mate.

Comment: hi om3r what if i need to add another word to exclude aside from undeliverable? i tried " Like '%undeliverable%' And 'Automatic reply'" but got a parse error. thanks man.

Comment: @wh3resmycar2 - Thank you for V1 and please post new Question and I will answer quickly -

Comment: sure man. thanks. i'm posting the question now. please watch out for it.

Comment: hey man it's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42777395/excel-vba-sql-string-filter-multiple-like-condition