# Excel VBA @SQL String filter Multiple LIKE Condition

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-filter

This code works as intended but I also need to exclude `Autoreplies` and some other strings in a subject line. I need to know if it's possible to add 2 or 3 more Likes.

I tried And and Or conditions but I'm getting a parse error.

This code below works. I just need to add another string condition after undeliverable. `" Like '%Automatic reply%'".`

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & " Not " & _
             "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & "" & _
             " Like '%undeliverable%'"
```

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**`OR`** Should work, The following Example have either `%undeliverable%` Or `%Automatic reply%`

---

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & " Not (urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   " Like '%undeliverable%'  Or " & _
                         "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   " Like '%Automatic reply%')"
```

---

To Add one more Filter

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & " Not (urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   " Like '%undeliverable%'  Or " & _
                         "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   " Like '%Automatic reply%' Or " & _
                         "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   " Like '%Bla Bla%')"
```

Comment: ok i'm not in the office anymore. so i can add another Or to make 3 filters then?

Comment: @wh3resmycar2 Yes- play with it- you get it :-)

Comment: ok i will try once i get back in the office. notice some parenthesis in the syntax.. i'll hit back once i test it. thanks man.