# Outlook-Excel VBA Macro IF NOT Statement

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Context: Every day we get lots of emails containing backup reports and we currently manually count through them and work out what is missing.

I have found a great bit of code (that runs using Visual Basic for Applications) that will pull the emails out of Outlook and put them in Excel.

Now I just need to get rid of the successful ones so it leaves the emails that in the subject line don't have "Result: OK."

```
 Public Sub CopyMailtoExcel()

    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim objItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim olItem As Object ' MailItem
    Dim strDisplayName, strAttCount, strBody, strDeleted As String
    Dim strReceived As Date
    Dim rCount As Long

'  On Error GoTo Err_Execute
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
rCount = rCount + 1

Set objOL = Outlook.Application

' copy mail to excel
Set objFolder = objOL.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder
Set objItems = objFolder.Items

For Each olItem In objItems
strAttCount = ""
strBody = ""

If olItem.Attachments.Count > 0 Then strAttCount = "Yes"

'On Error Resume Next
 'collect the fields
strBody = olItem.Body

' Remove this block if you don't want to remove the hyperlinked urls
Dim Reg1 As RegExp
Dim Match, Matches
Set Reg1 = New RegExp

' remove hyperlinks from bodies for easier reading.
With Reg1
        .Pattern = "<[src|http|mailto](.*)>(\s)*"
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = True

.MultiLine = True

End With

If Reg1.Test(strBody) Then
 strBody = Reg1.Replace(strBody, "")
End If
' end remove hyperlinks block


strBody = Trim(strBody)
strReceived = olItem.ReceivedTime
strSender = olItem.SenderName

' column / field
' A Date
' B Time
' C Attachments (Yes)
' D Subject
' E Body
' F From (display name)
' G To (display name)
' H CC (display name)
' I BCC (sent items only)

'write them in the excel sheet
 Range("A" & rCount) = strReceived ' format using short date
 Range("B" & rCount) = strReceived 'format using time
 Range("C" & rCount) = strAttCount
 Range("D" & rCount) = olItem.Subject
 Range("E" & rCount) = strBody
 Range("F" & rCount) = strSender
 Range("G" & rCount) = olItem.To
 Range("H" & rCount) = olItem.CC
 Range("I" & rCount) = olItem.BCC


'Next row
  rCount = rCount + 1
  Next


' Basic Formatting
Columns("A:I").Select
With Selection
    .WrapText = True
    .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
    .VerticalAlignment = xlTop
    .Columns.AutoFit
End With
Columns("E:E").Select ' body column
With Selection
    .ColumnWidth = 150
    .Rows.AutoFit
End With

Range("A1:I1").Select
 With Selection
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .RowHeight = 55
End With


' Date and Time
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-409]ddd mm/dd/yy;@"
Range("B:B").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "[$-F400]h:mm AM/PM"

Range("D:D").Select
Selection.ColumnWidth = 20


Range("A2").Select

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Set olItem = Nothing
Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
Set Reg1 = Nothing

MsgBox "Email import complete"

Exit Sub

Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred."

End Sub
```

Below is an example of a successful and a non working backup report email subject line. The profile name is different for each job so that will change. 
Success:

```
ViceVersa Notification. Profile: R4Data_D - Result: OK.  

Failure  
ViceVersa Notification. Profile: ST29 Data - Result: Source folder not found.
```

The failed ones won't always be as above as they fail for different reasons so I was thinking that I need an IF or IF NOT Statement of some sort that does something like this:

IF the subject line contains anything other than "Result: OK." then don't export

But I know it would need to allow for different Profile names etc.

The other option is to read out of the body of the email and in that case I would want the macro to only extract emails that don't have "Exit Code: 0" in the body of the email.

Sorry I have no idea about how to construct this!

Credit to original [Original Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsDW6.jpg)  Diane Poremsky

Comment: Does both emails have an attachment?

Comment: Filtering Items Using a String Comparison https://stackoverflow.com/a/42777485/4539709

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the following test:

```
If InStr(olItem.Subject, "Result: OK") = 0
```